# Finding the min and max value of a linked list within a specific range in C

Tags: c, linked-list

I have created a program in C where a CSV file consisting of coordinates and location IDs is inserted into a linked list. I'm trying find the minimum and maximum x coordinate that is greater than 20. However, when running the program, the output just keeps printing the first value in the linked list. How do i fix this?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <string.h>

#define MAX 50

struct wake {
    double x, y, id;
    struct wake *next;
}*head;                                                         

typedef struct wake ;

void read_csv();
void minmaxNode();

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    read_csv();
}

void read_csv() {
    FILE *fp = fopen("data.csv", "r");
    
    char buffer[MAX];
    struct wake** tail = &head;
    
    while (fgets(buffer, MAX, fp)) {
         *node = malloc(sizeof());
        node->x = atof(strtok(buffer, ","));
        node->y = atof(strtok(NULL, ","));
        node->id = atof(strtok(NULL, ","));
        node->next = NULL;
        *tail = node;
        tail = &node->next;
  
    }
    minmaxNode();
}

void minmaxNode() {  
    struct wake *current = head;  
    
    double min, max;
    //double min;
    
    if(head == NULL) {  
        printf("List is empty \n");  
    }  
    else {  
        //Initializing min with head node   
        min = current->x;
        max = current->x;
        
        
        while(current != NULL){  
            if (current->x > 20) {
                //If current node's  is smaller than min  
                //Then, replace value of min with current node's   
                if(min > current->x) {  
                    min = current->x;
                }
                if(max < current->x) {  
                    max = current->x;
                }  
                
                current= current->next;  
            }          
            printf("Min x: %lf\n",min); 
            printf("Max x: %lf\n",max);   
        }  
    }
}
```

Here is the input file:

```
19.743748,-11.838155,1.083537,-0.003929,0.947989
19.810734,-11.838155,1.083533,-0.004183,0.947972
19.877850,-11.838155,1.083525,-0.004426,0.947953
19.945097,-11.838155,1.083514,-0.004656,0.947930
20.012476,-11.838155,1.083501,-0.004868,0.947904
20.079988,-11.838155,1.083488,-0.005062,0.947875
20.147631,-11.838155,1.083478,-0.005237,0.947844
20.215405,-11.838155,1.083475,-0.005394,0.947812
```

Answer (score 2):

- You are doing `current= current->next;` only if `current->x > 20`.
  `x` of the first value is not greater than 20, so it will stack at that node.
- The head node data need not satisfy the condition, so it is bad to initialize `min` and `max` to head node data without range checking.
- To prevent it from printing intermediate result and have it print only the final result, printing statements should be *after* the loop, not *inside* the loop.

In conclusion, you should do

```
        //Flagging that we didn't see any valid data yet
        int data_exists = 0;
        min = 0;
        max = 0;
        
        while(current != NULL){
            if (current->x > 20) {
                //If current node's data is smaller than min
                //or we didn't see any valid data yet
                //Then, replace value of min with current node's data
                if(!data_exists || min > current->x) {
                    min = current->x;
                }
                if(!data_exists || max < current->x) {
                    max = current->x;
                }
                data_exists = 1; //Flag that now we see a valid data
                
            }
            current= current->next; // execute this regardless of the if statement
        }
        // print after the loop
        printf("Min x: %lf\n",min);
        printf("Max x: %lf\n",max);
```

instead of

```
        //Initializing min with head node data  
        min = current->x;
        max = current->x;
        
        
        while(current != NULL){  
            if (current->x > 20) {
                //If current node's data is smaller than min  
                //Then, replace value of min with current node's data  
                if(min > current->x) {  
                    min = current->x;
                }
                if(max < current->x) {  
                    max = current->x;
                }  
                
                current= current->next;  
            }          
            printf("Min x: %lf\n",min); 
            printf("Max x: %lf\n",max);   
        }
```

Comment: Sorry this doesn't work. Here's the output: https://i.stack.imgur.com/TD92z.png

Comment: I want my program to print just one 'Min x:' statement and one 'Max x:' statement.

Comment: @daf that a completely different bug. your output shouldn't be *inside* the loop; it should be after the closing `}` of the loop.

Comment: If I put the print output statements outside the loop, the min x value is below 20. I get this: https://i.stack.imgur.com/MdLeN.png

Comment: Are you sure the print statements are in the correct place? I had to put the print statements outside the while loop for it to work correctly. Please confirm.

Comment: I'm not sure because desired output is not given in your question.

Comment: When I placed the print statements outside the while loop, the correct max and min values were printed: https://i.stack.imgur.com/IlQFR.png

Answer (score 0):

This is the code that works correctly.

```
double min = 0, max = 0;
    int data_exists = 0;
    //double min;
    
    if(head == NULL) {  
        printf("List is empty \n");  
    }  
    else {  
        //Initializing min with head node data  
        while(current != NULL){
            if (current->x > 20) {
                //If current node's data is smaller than min
                //or we didn't see any valid data yet
                //Then, replace value of min with current node's data
                if(!data_exists || min > current->x) {
                    min = current->x;
                }
                if(!data_exists || max < current->x) {
                    max = current->x;
                }
                data_exists = 1; //Flag that now we see a valid data
                
            }
            current= current->next; // execute this regardless of the if statement
            
        }
        printf("Min x: %lf\n",min);
        printf("Max x: %lf\n",max);
        
    }
}
```